# gitlab-ci.yml bash script to update AWS route53 invalid yaml

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, yaml, gitlab, amazon-route53

I am trying to create a job in GitLab to update the DNS for an application when it is deployed.  I have a bash oneliner that works on the gitlab-runner.  But I can't get it to validate in the gitlab-ci.yml file.  This is the original script which runs on gitlab runner.

```
TARGET_ZONEID="Z2T1234"; TARGET_FQDN="appName.domain.com."; echo '{ "Comment": "DDNS update", "Changes":[ { "Action": "UPSERT", "ResourceRecordSet": { "ResourceRecords": [ { "Value": "web_server.domain.com" } ], "Name": "'"$TARGET_FQDN"'", "Type": "CNAME", "TTL": 60} } ] }'
```

This is how I have it in the Gitlab-ci.yml

```
update_public_dns:
  script: 
  - TARGET_ZONEID="Z2T1234"; TARGET_FQDN="appName.domain.com."; echo '{ "Comment": "DDNS update", "Changes":[ { "Action": "UPSERT", "ResourceRecordSet": { "ResourceRecords": [ { "Value": "web_server.domain.com" } ], "Name": "'"$TARGET_FQDN"'", "Type": "CNAME", "TTL": 60} } ] }'
```

That fails with the following error: **`(<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 3 column 5.`**

After searching the internet for hours I found a suggestion that indicated that I should escape all the quotes.  So I tried this: (notice I took out one of the variables to try to simplify the script.)

```
update_public_dns:
  script: 
  - echo '{ \"Comment\": \"DDNS update\", \"Changes\": [ { \"Action\": \"UPSERT\", \"ResourceRecordSet\": { \"ResourceRecords\": [ { \"Value\": \"web_server.panosoft.com\" } ], \"Name\": \"appName.domain.com\", \"Type\": \"CNAME\", \"TTL\": 60} } ] }' | aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id "Z2TLDA3UA15TJ8" --change-batch file:///dev/stdin'
```

The result is this error:

```
(<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 3 column 54
```

I am now at my wits end trying to figure this out.  Any suggestions?

FYI, I don't want to create a bash script and then call it from gitlab, because I entend to use project variable to customize the web_server and appName settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a plain scalar (without quotes), as in your first YAML example, you cannot have sequences like `:` (colon+space) as these would indicate a key-value pair.

If you make that into a double quoted scalar, you have to escape the double quotes and any existing backslashes with backslashes.
If you make that into a single quotes scalar, you have to escape any single quote by doubling it.

The easiest way to get your string into a scalar is to make it a block style literal scalar:

```
update_public_dns:
  script: 
  - |-
    TARGET_ZONEID="Z2T1234"; TARGET_FQDN="appName.domain.com."; echo '{ "Comment": "DDNS update", "Changes":[ { "Action": "UPSERT", "ResourceRecordSet": { "ResourceRecords": [ { "Value": "web_server.domain.com" } ], "Name": "'"$TARGET_FQDN"'", "Type": "CNAME", "TTL": 60} } ] }'
```

Within such a scalar no escapes are done and `:` can occur without causing problems. The the dash after `|` indicates that the final newline needs to be stripped.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  This validates now.  However, when I add the last section where it pipes to aws I get an error.  This is what the pipe looks like `| aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id "$TARGET_ZONEID" --change-batch file:///dev/stdin` and this is the error: `/bin/bash: line 48: aws: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
`  I have verified that aws is installed and runnable by the gitlab-runner user.

Comment: Also, by using a literal scalar, am i giving up the ability to use variables in my gitlab-ci.yml file for this command?

Comment: Please post a new question with exactly what you use, and the error. You can link to this post to provide some context, but I don't think the problem comes from the YAML. I have no experience with amazon-web-services (I'm more the YAML guy), so I probably cannot help. But since you mentioned that you didn't want to create a script (inflexible), you could still do that to make sure you have all of the commands correct.

Comment: I have no idea how gitlab evaluates the variables. But if they use a standard YAML parser, the program has no knowledge about what kind of scalar was the source for the loaded string. Thus if they do the expanding of the variables after loading, its is unlikely that this should differ. If they expand on the YAML source, before parsing, it might be more of a problem, but also not necessarily.

Comment: As I indicated (we're cross posting comments here) they would have to hook their variable expansion into the parser to be able to distinguish between plain scalar and literal scalar (or quoted scalar). I recently looked at their software to see how they use YAML and if extra tagged objects could be loaded, but it is in Ruby and that discouraged me to investigate (nothing against Ruby, but I am not proficient enough in it to read sources).